# Kohana - Session Database

Tags: php, mysql, session, kohana, kohana-3

I'm attempting to use the session database with Kohana 3.

I have setup the mysql database as described here: http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=sessions_and_cookies

I am setting session variables like so:

```
Session::instance('database')->set('uid', $user_id);
```

However when I go to fetch the data back later on a different page or refresh it returns NULL.

```
Session::instance('database')->get('uid', NULL);
```

But if I put them right next to each other it works fine... i.e.

```
Session::instance('database')->set('uid', $user_id);
Session::instance('database')->get('uid', NULL);
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I have also setup session.php in my config folder which looks like this:

```
<?php

    return array(
      'cookie' => array(
          'name' => 'cookie',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'native' => array(
          'name' => 'session',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'database' => array(
          'group' => 'default',
          'table' => 'sessions',
      ),
  );

?>
```

Cheers,
Thomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the session.php file to look like this:

```
<?php

    return array(
      'cookie' => array(
          'name' => 'session_cookie',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'native' => array(
          'name' => 'session_native',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'database' => array(
          'name' => 'session_database',
          'group' => 'default',
          'table' => 'sessions',
      ),
  );

?>
```

Problem was by default the sessions are called 'session'.

So I renamed each adapter and it has fixed the issue.

Comment: Correct. Every session type must have a different name. The "name" is the cookie name. Multiple cookies with the same name will overwrite each other.